# Update attribute after button click with Javascript on Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm trying to make a Javacript function on Microsoft Dynamics 365 Ribbon Workbench , when I click on it, it is supposed to update my value . . Here's my code below because I've been stuck for few days and it doesn't seem to work. If the button is clicked on, update the attribute.

```
function setAlert(primaryControl)
{
    var formContext= primaryControl;
formContext.getControl("aa__numberofthings").getAttribute("aa__numberofthings").setValue("you cannot enter value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
formContext.getAttribute(arg).setValue(value)
```

---

```
formContext.getAttribute("aa__numberofthings").setValue("you cannot enter value");
```

[SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/attributes/setvalue)